# Null set of reals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble to understand a step of a proof.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $S$ is null (Lebesgue measure).

The book says the following:

**"It is clear that we can restrict ourselves to subsets of the unit interval; thus assume that $S\subset [0,1]$"**

I don't understand why that is true. I've tried to prove it by seeing that what happens in $[0,1]$, happens in $[n,n+1]$  $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$, but I'm not even sure whether that would work or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If one can show that the intersection with any $[n,n+1]$ is null, then the whole set is null.

Comment: Are you asking whether the statement in bold holds? If so, then it is impossible to reply without knowing what $S$ is.

Comment: @Jonas I'm asking that, yes. Well, I'm afraid that there isn't any more information about $S$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. Let's assume you have proved the statement in the case $S \subset [0,1]$. Now in the general case you can split $S$ by considering the subsets
$$
S_n = S \cap [n, n+1].
$$
Since the Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation, you can assume that each of the $S_n$ sets are contained in $[0,1]$, i.e. $\mathcal{L}(S_n) = \mathcal{L}(\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x+n \in S_n\}). $ And so you can conclude using what you proved in the "easy case".

Comment: How do you know that $S_n-n$ is independent of $n$?

Comment: What do you mean by independent? I'm just trying to show a way to understand that step of the proof. But of course I can't go further since we don't know the contest and we don't know absolutely anything about $S$...

Comment: To be independent means that $S_n-n=S_m-m$ for any $n$ and $m$.

Comment: We don't know that. But we do know that $\mathcal{L}(S_n) = \mathcal{L}(S_n - n)$ . Since $S_n - n \subset [0,1]$, if it's possible (we should know better about the contest), we can apply the previous step of the proof to $S_n - n$.

Comment: OK, thanks. So we do agree.

Comment: Yes, and I do agree with you that we can't give a proper proof here, but we can just point the possible solution, since there is a big lack of information here..